# zsh - how does the indexing for this associative array work?

Tags: zsh

The code below seems to be working correctly:

```sh
#!/bin/zsh

zparseopts -D -E -A opts f -foo

if [[ -n ${opts[(ie)-f]} || -n ${opts[(ie)--foo]} ]]; then
  echo "foo is set."
else
  echo "foo is not set."
fi
```

```sh
~/tmp > ./args.sh         
foo is not set.
~/tmp > ./args.sh -f      
foo is set.
~/tmp > ./args.sh --foo   
foo is set.
```

What does the syntax for the index of `opts` mean i.e. `(ie)-f`? Is there some documentation where I can learn more about this? I don't even know what to search for to learn more about this kind of indexing.

Comment: Why is the bash tag present on this question?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy- Sorry, I thought this was something to do with associative arrays which are present in bash as well? Is this a zsh only feature?

Comment: It's definitely a feature bash also has, but the implementation is different enough that an answer for one shell is not likely to work for the other. They're not mutually compatible, so what's the point of tagging for an language and interpreter other than the one you actually need a working answer for?

Comment: (for example, `${(k)anything}` is not meaningful syntax in bash in the first place; the way one extracts an array's keys in bash is with `"${!array[@]}"` -- so reading the answer to this zsh-centric question would not help someone who had a comparable question about bash).

Answer (score 0):

My bad - I found it in the zsh manual [here](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Guide/zshguide05.html). It's explained in section `5.4.2 Using Associative Arrays`.

To explain, it seems like this is a part of `parameter substitutions` in `zsh`. I don't know if it applies to `bash` as well.

This allows you to use certain "parameters" to perform some functionalities.

The syntax is to include the parameters within parentheses and prefix the specific part of the object that you want to substitute, modify etc.

For example, taking `opts` in my question,

```sh
echo ${opts}
```

prints the values of the associative array.

We have the parameter `k` which signifies the keys and `v` which signifies values. This can be used as follows:

```sh
echo ${(k)opts}  # print only the keys
echo ${(kv)opts} # print the keys and values
```

To answer the main part of my question, what does `(ie)-f` mean, these are parameters that apply to the index of the associative array. Looking at the manual I had linked to, here is what `i` does - it searches for the key and returns the **key** instead of the value.

Explanation from the manual:

> If instead of an ordinary subscript you use a subscript preceded by the flag (i), the shell will search for a matching key (not value) with the pattern given and return that. This is deliberately the same as searching an ordinary array to get its key (which in that case is just a number, the index), but note this time it doesn't match on the value, it really does match, as well as return, the key

And with regards to `e` - this seems a bit more complicated. But reading through the manual, it seems like this further evaluates the value if necessary i.e. in the event that it's not a constant.

Here is an example:

```sh
bar=4
foo='$bar'

> echo $foo
$bar

> echo ${(e)foo}    
4
```

So combining the two together `(ie)` in my question returns the key and also expands it if necessary.

Comment: Please include the relevant explanation in the answer, not just a link to the manual.